# WP_Query with custom post type ID

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development, loop, wp-query

This code isn't echoing out anything, even though I'm 100% positive $mixtape_id is set to an integer which corresponds to one of the posts within the 'mixtapes' custom post type

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'      => 'mixtapes',
  'p'              => (int)$mixtape_id,
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key'       => 'track_number'
));

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<track>
    <location>track1.mp3</location>
    <creator>Artist name</creator>
    <title>Track 1</title>
</track>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: "even though I'm 100% positive $mixtape_id is set to an integer" ... did you `var_dump`?

Comment: yes i typed it in manually with a number. I figured it out though, i used a different loop

Comment: @Tallboy - you mean you found the issue? If so, post it as an answer...

Comment: It mainly has to do with my specific setup instead of a problem i was typing (although that code above should definitely have worked). ill put what i actually typed though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by doing it a different way

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'      => 'tracks',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key'       => 'track_number',
  'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
        'meta_key'   => 'mixtape',
        'meta_value' => (string)$mixtape_id
    )
  )
));
```

Comment: p.s. you should use a more unique variable name than `$query`, which is far too generic. I would use something like `$mixtape_query`.

Comment: Don't forget to mark yourself as the answer bud!